# Debugging golang running under AppEngine in Liteide

Tags: google-app-engine, debugging, go, gdb, liteide

I'm writing a little API using go and Google AppEngine. All of this is in Liteide and TBH after a little pain setting up, is now working beautifully well. I've got to the point where I need to start debugging in GDB, this is all signed and Liteide is picking this up. There is however a problem that I can't overcome and that is getting GDB to load the symbols for the application. The following is an excerpt from the console:

```
&"Warning: /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime: No such file or directory.\n"
10000008^done,source-path="/usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime:$cdir:$cwd"
(gdb) 
&"set substitute-path /go/src/pkg/runtime /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime\n"
10000009^done
(gdb) 
10000010^error,msg="No symbol table is loaded.  Use the \"file\" command."
(gdb) 
10000011^error,msg="No symbol table is loaded.  Use the \"file\" command."
(gdb) 
10000012^error,msg="No symbol table is loaded.  Use the \"file\" command."
(gdb) 
10000013^error,msg="No executable file specified.\nUse the \"file\" or \"exec-      file\" command."
(gdb)
```

It seems that GDB is looking in the wrong place for the runtime but then possibly substituting this for the correct path? I'm running AppEngine from

```
"/Applications/go_appengine 2/dev_appserver.py"
```

and I have a suspicion that I need to tell GDB to debug a particular process but I'm not sure what and where so configure that. Doe anyone have any experience of how to set this up or where I might be going wrong?